# Liferay custom structure ID

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Setting in `liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties`:

```
journal.structure.force.autogenerate.id=false
journal.template.force.autogenerate.id=false
```

used to enable YOU **editing structure and template id**.

This DOES NOT work anymore in liferay 6.2

Using liferay 5.x (and I've read [on the web](http://gwofu.wordpress.com/tag/journal-template/) about liferay 6.1) was fine.

Does anybody know how to do this again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a fix implemented for this in Liferay 6.2 EE. I am experiencing the same problem on Liferay 6.2 CE though. Hopefully I will be able to solve it.

The fix is discussed in the following Liferay Issue: https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-48441. You can follow it as a possible direction to get the solution.

Regards.

EDIT: If you want to "avoid the patching" of this issue, you could use the Scripting Console from the Control Panel and change the structures or templates ids running a script. You can get it from my response in the Liferay thread in here:

[Structures and Templates Ids autogeneration not working - Liferay 6.2 CE GA2](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/45257231)

Comment: Yep I started the discussione here https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/45171784 and I've been notified that a solution is available for next CE release. https://github.com/brianchandotcom/liferay-portal/pull/19818

Answer (score 0):

Structure-Template of Journal Article got changes in Liferay 6.2 version.

```
dynamic.data.mapping.structure.force.autogenerate.id=false
dynamic.data.mapping.template.force.autogenerate.key=true
```

are the new properties for having structure-id and template-id as editable.

Comment: Sorry did not work.
The only property I coud use to force id's is ```journal.article.force.autogenerate.id=false``` which works for articles